# What is the fastest way to compute the dot product of two matrices in Python (and Cython)

Tags: python, cython, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to make a Python library with Cython, and I need to implement the dot product into it. I have a very simple method of calculating the dot product, however, it does not run fast enough with larger matrices.

I have spent lots of time googling this problem, and trying to make it go as fast as possible, however I am unable to make it go any faster.

The code below shows a Python implementation of how I am currently computing it:

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = [[1], [2], [3]]

def dot(a, b):
    c = [[0 for j in range(len(b[i]))] for i in range(len(a))]

    for i in range(len(c)):
        for j in range(len(c[i])):
            t = 0
            for k in range(len(b)):
                t += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
            c[i][j] = t
    return c

print(dot(a, b))
# [[14], [32]]
```

This does give the correct result of the calculation (`python [[14], [32]]`), however, it takes too long to compute for what I am going to use it for. Any help as to how I can make this faster would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why not just use numpy? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: So your primary data structure is a python list of lists?  What are you doing to adapt this to cython?

Comment: Just using cdef. Also, the primary data structure is a custom class that acts as a list, just with different functions.

Comment: There's a lot of discussion on how to get the most speed out of `cython` - some here, some in the cython docs.  The key is to minimize uses of Python structures and objects, and maximizing direct translation to `C`.  This is hard to do with lists, which have 'pointers' to other Python objects.  Numpy arrays on the other hand store their data in flat databuffers.  The `typed memoryviews` cython page is good reading.

Comment: There's a range of questions that you'd do well to read if you [search for "`[cython] dot product`"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcython%5D+dot+product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should annotate (*i.e.*, statically type) all the variables possible. Below is my solution, if you'd like:

```py
# mydot.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport cython

def dot_1(a, b):
    c = [[0 for j in range(len(b[i]))] for i in range(len(a))]

    for i in range(len(c)):
        for j in range(len(c[i])):
            t = 0
            for k in range(len(b)):
                t += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
            c[i][j] = t
    return c


@cython.boundscheck(False)  # turn off bounds-checking
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping
def dot_2(double[:, :] A, double[:, :] B):
    cdef Py_ssize_t M = A.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t Na = A.shape[1]
    cdef Py_ssize_t Nb = B.shape[0]
    cdef Py_ssize_t K = B.shape[1]

    assert Na == Nb

    result = np.empty((M, K), dtype='d')
    cdef double[:, :] C = result

    cdef double t

    for m in range(M):
        for k in range(K):
            t = 0
            for n in range(Na):
                t += A[m, n] * B[n, k]
            C[m, k] = t

    return result
```

and

```py
# app.py
import pyximport
from numpy import array
from scipy import median
from timeit import repeat

pyximport.install()
from mydot import dot_1, dot_2


a = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype='d')
b = array([[1], [2], [3]], dtype='d')

dot_1_t = repeat('dot_1(a, b)', repeat=1000, number=1, globals=globals())
dot_2_t = repeat('dot_2(a, b)', repeat=1000, number=1, globals=globals())

print(f'dot_1 took {median(dot_1_t)*1000} ms.')
print(f'dot_2 took {median(dot_2_t)*1000} ms.')
```

When you run `cython --annotate mydot.pyx`, Cython will generate an HTML file annotating the Cython code. There, the darker the yellow highlights are, the more (Python) overhead the generated C code has. You can compare the two solutions (especially the `for` loops) against each other.

Running `python app.py` should also give you faster results. Of course, if you supply smaller sized inputs below some threshold, you won't see a meaningful speed difference between the two because you are not iterating enough. However, after some threshold, the speed difference should be significant because each iteration in the loop will be costly for your version (cf. darker yellow lines).

One last remark is that, as everybody under this question has already suggested, when you provide matrices having larger dimensions, `numpy`'s functions should be more performant --- they are using blocked (sub)matrix operations from the underlying BLAS and LAPACK implementations rather than naively iterating the indices one by one.

P.S: If you want to specialize `dot_2` not only on `double`s but also other meaningful arithemtic types such as `int`s and `float`s, you should check Cython's [fused types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html).

**EDIT.** Because my response was later selected as the answer, I wanted to give an example of larger-sized inputs. If, instead of `app.py` above, one uses the following:

```py
# app.py
import pyximport
from numpy import array, random as rnd
from scipy import median
from timeit import repeat

pyximport.install()
from mydot import dot_1, dot_2


M = 100
N = 100
K = 1

a = rnd.randn(M, N)
b = rnd.randn(N, K)

dot_1_t = repeat('dot_1(a, b)', repeat=1000, number=1, globals=globals())
dot_2_t = repeat('dot_2(a, b)', repeat=1000, number=1, globals=globals())

print(f'dot_1 took {median(dot_1_t)*1000} ms.')
print(f'dot_2 took {median(dot_2_t)*1000} ms.')
```

the timings should read something similar to the below:

```
dot_1 took 5.218300502747297 ms.
dot_2 took 0.013017997844144702 ms.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy` for this. Numpy implements the BLAS specification (Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms), they are the de facto standard for low-level routines (like matrix multiplication) for linear algebra libraries. To get the dot-product of two matrices, say `A` and `B` you can use the following code:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
B = [[1], [2], [3]]

import numpy as np #Import numpy

numpy_a = np.array(A) #Cast your nested lists to numpy arrays
numpy_b = np.array(B)
print(np.dot(numpy_a, numpy_b)) #Print the result
```

Comment: I understand that I could use NumPy, however, I was trying to refrain, both for learning purposes and so that I can understand exactly how everything works, but thank you for your answer

Comment: I understand. However, Numpy is the fastest way for things like this in python, because of BLAS. If you wish to implement this yourself; go ahead... I warn you though, it won't be easy. Check out [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) and [BLAS and LAPACK in numpy](https://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html) if you want to go ahead with this. My two cents: use numpy and move on to greater things =) No need to re-invent the wheel

Comment: I understand that what I am doing is nearly pointless, and that things already exist that will be able to run much faster than anything I could ever make, however, I will use these links as best as I can to implement those methods, even though I hardly understand any of it... Thanks

Comment: I'm not saying its pointless - I'm saying that these operations already have been created in such an optimal/easy to implement way, that it might not be worthwhile to really get to the bottom of how its implemented. Unless you have a specific reason for wanting to understand all this. In any case, I wish you the best of luck. BTW; If one of the answers fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). It lets everyone on SO know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the indexing cost of structure you might gain some speed by factoring out some operations:

```
def dot(a, b):
    c = [[0 for j in range(len(b[i]))] for i in range(len(a))]
    bt = transpose(b)        # can this be done once cheaply?
    for i in range(len(c)):
        a1 = a[i]
        c1 = c[i]
        for j in range(len(c1)):
            b1 = bt[j]
            t = 0
            for k in range(len(b)):
                t += a1[k] * b1[k]
            c1[j] = t
    return c
```

The inner `k` loop can be written, with idiomatic Python as:

```
for a2, b2 in zip(a1, b1):
     t += a2 * b2
```

I don't know if that's faster in a cython translation.

Fast cython also requires defining various variables as `int`, `float` etc, so it can make direct `c` translations, rather than going through general, but expensive, Python objects.  I won't try to repeat cython documentation.

Comment: This is an interesting thought, however some testing shows that this method (at least when running in Cython) runs slower than my current implementation. This may be due to the slowness of the indexing, though I am unsure.